# What is HTTP Status 304 and am I to be alarmed by it?

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

When I go to monitor the 'network tab' of Google Chrome developer tool when loading
a particular site, I notice that lots of resources (e.g. the PNG and GIF files) receive
HTTP status 304.
Is this something to be alarmed about? Why?

Comment: Google can tell you what that HTTP status code means. Did you make any effort to search for it at all?

Answer (score 0):

It means:
304 NOT MODIFIED
It means no need to transmit the request
Its not an "error"